# Google Drive does not download files that have been loaded with another program in C # always done by me

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have made an application in C # that can be loaded into a folder created on google drive any file. I wanted to create another app that downloads the files to Android smartphone. My problem is that my app in Android does not see the files to be downloaded even though it is in the drive folder. I noticed that if I load the Android app files and then discharge from the same app works.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, please see this:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive

It explains that your Android app must create its GoogleApiClient with either `SCOPE_FILE` or `SCOPE_APP_FOLDER` scope. You'll see that those are defined as:

> **SCOPE_APPFOLDER:** A Scope that gives 'drive.appfolder' access to a user's drive. This scope gives access to files that have been created by the app in the App Folder.
>
> **SCOPE_FILE:** A Scope that gives 'drive.file' access to a user's drive. This scope give per-file access to files that have been created by, or specifically opened with the app.

What this means is that your app can only open files that have been either created by your app or specifically opened by the user via your app's use of the Google Drive API.

If there's something else you're trying to do, you may have to design a different approach.